# how to create database using php in hostgator shared hosting account?

Tags: php, cpanel

I can create database manually by going to cpanel. But I'd like to create databases using php. I've tried using the code from w#school.com , but it don't work. How do i create database using php?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost",cpname_DbUsername,password);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE " . cpName_NewDbName,$con))
  {
  echo "Database created";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The above code give me error :(
btw, i tried to ask in hostgator sup[port forum but i cant make a new threat in their forum :(

Comment: I believe you can't. Because database must be created through hostgator's cpanel.

Comment: @deceze, it saying access denied

Comment: @ariefbayu, i thought the same thing. But now i'm skeptical about it cos databases were created automatically  wen i installed CMS using their auto installer! So, there must be a way to create database programatically

Comment: @NokImchen: YES!, because you are using **their** auto installer. It's pretty common in web hosting industry, to automatically create database and basic setting on auto installer cms. To help new user start faster.

Comment: Try running `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'yourdatabase_username'@'localhost';` as the query and `print_r` the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a shared host, you won't have permissions to create a database through PHP because they regulate the number of databases you can have. You'll need to do it through their control panel. On a sidenote, you should probably use PDO (or a more powerful abstraction layer if the app warrants it) for a new webapp. php_mysql is deprecated. Also, w3schools is a [bad, non-authoritative resource](http://w3fools.com).

Answer (score 2):

```
function create_db($cPanelUser,$cPanelPass,$dbName) {

$buildRequest = "/frontend/x3/sql/addb.html?db=".$dbName;

$openSocket = fsockopen('localhost',2082);
if(!$openSocket) {
    return "Socket error";
    exit();
}

$authString = $cPanelUser . ":" . $cPanelPass;
$authPass = base64_encode($authString);
$buildHeaders  = "GET " . $buildRequest ."\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "Host:localhost\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "Authorization: Basic " . $authPass . "\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "\r\n";

fputs($openSocket, $buildHeaders);
while(!feof($openSocket)) {
    fgets($openSocket,128);
}
fclose($openSocket);


//echo "Created database $dbName";

}
create_db('username','password','dbname');
```

Comment: Is this a secure method?

Comment: The secure port is 2083, whereas the insecure port is 2082... so probably not.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if the username and password and mysql db name are correct, and have the permission to access the database.

Then, try to use the new approach to connect to the database which is called the `PDO`

here's the manual [PDO MANUAL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score -1):

What I do to create a database in Hostgator out from CPanel, I use [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) , here's some step you have to do get it done! [Click Here!](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/managing-your-database-with-applications)
From workbench you are able to manage all database that are in your host.

Workbench it's a pretty easy tool to use!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.